# Hiding FCGI script name from URL with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, flask

I am trying to configure Flask with Apache and FCGI. I am using .htaccess config given below. The problem I am trying to fix is removing "app.fcgi" from URLs generated with Flask's url_for().

For example, if I have a form at www.example.com/my_form, then after submitting it I am seeing www.example.com/**app.fcgi**/my_form and I would like it to be www.example.com/my_form without app.fcgi

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !=<path_to_dir>/app.fcgi
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized that this can be fixed from app.fcgi by using ScriptNameStripper shown here http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/fastcgi/